# Adding line breaks in WooCommerce order processing emails

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I had to add some text to the customer-processing-order.php (email) but it’s just one big body of text. I need to add some line breaks but nothing I have tried is working.

Does anyone know how I could add line breaks to the text that the customer sees in the email they get after placing an order?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried separating paragraphs using HTML's `<p>` tag?
That's what the default template is doing and seems to work just fine.

Comment: I used an opening and closing <p> tag on each paragraph but the email just shows those <p> tags without any line breaks. I also tried <br> and nbsp; but no breaks. It's like IN the body of text to be displayed, it doesn't acknowledge any html.